# Create Task in Asana Node.js

Tags: node.js, asana, asana-api

Using the below in Node trying to create a task within Workspace. I have omitted the AccessToken & WorkspaceID numbers. Suspect I'm doing something really dumb :)

```
var asana = require('asana');
var client = asana.Client.create().useAccessToken('0/XXXXXXXX');
var newTask = { name: "Your Mission" };

client.tasks.createInWorkspace(1111111111, newTask).then(function(response) {
  tasks = response.data;
  console.log(tasks);
});
```

At runtime I get the following output...

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid Request
    at InvalidRequest.AsanaError (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/asana/lib/errors/error.js:4:11)
    at new InvalidRequest (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/asana/lib/errors/invalid_request.js:5:14)
    at Request._callback (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/asana/lib/dispatcher.js:152:23)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/D/Asana_Crons/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see with your code is that the workspace id needs to be a string, not an integer.  This is documented in the  [tasks section of /gen folder](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana/blob/master/lib/resources/gen/tasks.js) in the Asana Node client library.